# How to roundup the values

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

How to roundup the values in one line in juypter network ?

Store_type

e-Shop            1.062168e+08

Flagship store    5.229261e+07

MBR               5.216797e+07

TeleShop          4.938094e+07

Comment: What is the output that you desire? Can you provide an instance?

Comment: i want to make a pie chart . so i want that how to roundup these values in single line of python code .

Comment: i have tried this  :-                                                     total_amt_coll=data.groupby('Store_type')['total_amt'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
total_amt_coll

Comment: Give is a desierd output so we can help you. And how  do you store these values? Do you mean all the columns at once?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to round up to the next integer value, so you would want to use a function like this `math.ceil()` you can find out more about this function [here](https://kodify.net/python/math/round-integers/), it just rounds up your value to an integer that.

Comment: math.ceil() is used a single value at a time .i want the whole 4 lines of code excectes in one.

Comment: So you want to add the values together and then get the round up from the sum of them"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have pandas data frame `df`, just try the following:

```
df.round(2)
```

If you want to round specific columns only, then pass a dict where keys are colnames and values are `n` decimal to round.

```
df.round({"mycol": 2})
```

By default the former round all numeric columns to 2 decimals. (0 means integer parts only, i.e floor function).

See the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html).